# pass C++ object from C++ to Java as function argument

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I'd like to pass C++ object from C++ to Java as function argument. I use SWIG to generate Java bindings for my class definition(named "MyObj"). I use the following method(env is a JNIEnv*),

```
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, my_obj);
```

where "cls" corresponds to a class I get via "env->FindClass" and "mid" points to a static method of it. When I run the program, however, in that method("mid") I found that my argument is just a null pointer.

I also tried to use (jobject)(&my_obj) but it also doesn't work. Did I miss something? Thanks so much!

Comment: What exactly is the type of `my_obj`, and how was `my_obj` created?

Comment: It's a C++ class (not necessarily POD). my_obj is created on the stack in C++. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Are you checking for java exceptions on the c++ side? And is your class that your passing it just a class rather than a pointer to the class etc? If you want to pass something from a c++ pointer construct a jlong and use SetLongArrayRegion to place the pointed data in a sendable object. All depends on how complex your class is of course, if it's just small maybe you'll have an easier time sending it's member variables

Comment: if you are trying to pass pure c++ object to java, you need firstly make an proper java object from it. To make this, call java constructor made by swig that takes pointer of native (c++) object as parameter (like: `jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/MyJavaObject"); jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "(JZ)V"); jobject j_my_obj = env->NewObject(clazz, mid, cptr, 1);`), and then pass newly created `j_my_obj` to your static method.

Comment: Thanks! But seems this is not efficient? In Boost.Python I can pass an C++ object by reference to a Python function without making copy